# Is there a Gensim or any other Python package function to automatically generate a labeling for topic models?

Tags: python, text-mining, gensim, topic-modeling

I have a set of topic models generated by Gensim's LDA model.
I would like them being automatically labeled so I can pick meaningful labels for each topic more easily.
I have come across a function in R language's **textmineR** package called **LabelTopics**, which I believe does what I am looking for.
I wanted to know if there is any function for this matter similar to the mentioned R package's function available in Python packages like Gensim.

Please let me know. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The closest offered by Gensim's LDA class is the method `get_topic_terms()`, which lists the words most associated with a topic – from which you could conceivably autogenerate a crude label, or use as advice to a more manual approach.

See: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/ldamodel.html#gensim.models.ldamodel.LdaModel.get_topic_terms